# _("str") in Python , meaning of both

Tags: python, django

I am a starter in python. Now I am working on a Django project.
I saw many lines of code containing  `_('password')`, `_('last_login')` etc.
Check the code below:

```
    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
```

What is the use of `_('username')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Django the [`gettext` function is often imported as `_` for convenience](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation)